# Get only the required lines from a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

How to get every 3rd lines from a csv file using python?

```
import csv

with open ('data.csv','r') as infile:
    contents = csv.reader(infile, delimiter =' ')
then???
```

The csv file looks like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
only recquired line
cccccccccccccccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddddddddddddddd
only recquired line
```

The result should look like:

```
only recquired line
only recquired line
```

Comment: Nah, please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid loading the entire file into memory, you could use [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
from itertools import islice
with open ('data.csv','r') as infile:
    x = islice(infile, 2, None, 3)
    for line in x:
            print line
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that before.  Why is the second parameter (start) a 2?

Comment: @SteveP. since the OP needs every third line, the start is set to 2(index of the third line from the file)

Comment: +1 Ah, for some reason, I assumed that it was every third line, but starting at the first line...

Answer (score 3):

```
for index, line in enumerate(fileOfInterest, 1):
   if index % 3 == 0:
       doSomething
```

Alternatively, you can use python's [extended slice](http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) notation as in:

```
for line in fileOfInterest[2::3]
   doSomething
```

However, 1_CR's answer is the one I would go with!

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('test.csv') as hf:
    print [line for line in list(hf)[2::3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [extended slice notation](http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html):

```
for i in contents.splitlines(True)[2::3]:
    print (i)
```

Comment: if you really had to split on newline you may as well use [splitlines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) passing in keepends=True

Comment: Nice idea. I'll add that.

Comment: it should be `contents.splitlines(True)[2::3]`